# Capture the type of error it is returning (500,503,402, etc) and add that in the message

Tags: bash

How do I make this script to capture the type of error it is returning (500,503,402, etc) and add that in the message?

```
#!/bin/bash
hostlist=(s-example1.us s-example.2.us)
  for host in "${hostlist[@]}"; do
if nc -w 2 -z $host 80; then
    echo "INFO: ssh on $host responding [Looks Good]"
else
    echo "ERROR: ssh on $host not responding[Ooops something went 
  wrong]"
fi
done
```

Comment: 500,503,402? O.o Exit status is usually < 256. Are you confusing this with HTTP status codes?

Answer (score 1):

`$?` holds the status code of the last command run. So you can modify your else block to be:

```
else
    LAST_STATUS_CODE=$? # save the status code immediately, we don't want to accidentally overwrite it
    echo "ERROR: ssh on $host not responding[Ooops something went wrong]"
    echo "status code: $LAST_STATUS_CODE"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be mixing up SSH, HTTP, exit status and HTTP status codes. If you want HTTP status codes, use something like curl:

```
$ curl -LI google.com -s | grep 'HTTP/'
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Then:

```
#!/bin/bash
hostlist=(s-colin.coverhound.us s-joe.coverhound.us)
for host in "${hostlist[@]}"; do
    status=$(curl -LI "$host" -s | grep 'HTTP/')
    if [[ $status == *"200 OK"* ]]; then
        echo "INFO: HTTP on $host responding [Looks Good]"
    else
        echo "ERROR: HTTP on $host not responding [Ooops something went wrong]"
        printf "%s\n" "$status"
    fi
done
```

So, with `hostlist=(google.com/teapot)` I'd get:

```
ERROR: HTTP on $host not responding [Ooops something went wrong]
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
HTTP/1.1 418 I'm a Teapot
```

Comment: Thankyou so much. But the script throws "$host not responding"message for the working (good status) server too. It looks for the if condition and prints the "$host not responding"message for the all the servers.

Comment: @SureshRavi ouch, I was testing the `host` variable instead of the `status` one. Fixed it.